# Discord.js record audio

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i'm trying to make a multi-purpose bot, and want it to record multiple voice channels once a user joins, here is my current code:

```
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldVoiceState, newVoiceState) => {
if (newVoiceState.channel) {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get("798526132320337970");
    channel.join()
    console.log(`${newVoiceState} joined VC`)
} else if (oldVoiceState.channel) {
    console.log('user left VC')
    const channel = //THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
    if (channel.members.size === 1) {
        channel.leave()
    } else return;
}
```

I cant figure out how to add the bot to the user's voice-channel, and how to make the bot be able to record audio from multiple voice channels, and servers at once

Comment: Your bot can only be in one voice channel person server.

Comment: Just a side note, you should make sure the users in the voice channels know they're being recorded (and ask for permission).

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Discord API only permits your Bot ( and any other user ), to be in only 1 Voice Channel. You can only use multiple Bot-Accounts to be able to do what you want to do.

For more information read https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/voice.